# Retweet behaviour and partitions

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, nosql

I am implementing a timeline behaviour were users can reshare content across timelines with their followers similar to retweet on Twitter.

When a user posts content I am getting all his Followers and creating a Timeline object for each Follower. The Timeline object has the partitionkey set as the FollowerId. Hence when a user want´s to view his Following timeline I simply get Timeline objects by his userId.

The problem is when resharing/retweeting the content is duplicated outside the followers list. So when I need to update the Timeline object e.g. (number of likes, or the content itself). I need to get all the Timeline objects that have the same ContentId but since it is partitioned by the FollowerId I can´t query it because it is cross-partitioned.

I am using Stored Procedure btw for handling Timeline object updates.

Since resharing(retweeting) can really grow fast in numbers what would be the recommended way to handle this?

Is it possible to have two indpendent partitionkeys for the same object?

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible to have two independent partition keys for the same object in DocumentDB. To do this, you have to store the same data twice with the two different partition keys.

The pattern that social networks follow is similar to email mailboxes. Data is redundantly copied to each user's mailbox/partition key (with a short expiration period). So when someone tweets, you asynchronously (using DocumentDB's change feed or another queue/broker) write it to anyone who's following the user so that it appears in their stream. Every user independently reads only their duplicated copy using their partition key.

A common special case to this is "celebrities" - most systems have special handling because you don't want to duplicate data 1M times for someone with a large number of followers. So you use a combination of both approaches - duplicate data by default, and individually retrieve tweets for top users.